# bash function does not work in zsh env

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have used this simple bash function to check if ip is valid and it works fine, when I use `source checkip.sh && isvalidip 127.0.0.1 && echo $?` in bash env. but the same thing does not work when I am in zsh environment and always returns not valid ($? == 1).

Any idea how can make it work in zsh? (I want to use it as a function in shell env)

```
#!/bin/bash 
isvalidip(){                                                                         
 case $1 in                                                             
     "" | *[!0-9.]* | *[!0-9]) return 1 ;;                              
 esac                                                                   

 local IFS=.                                                           
 set -- $1                                                              

 [ "$#" -eq 4 ] && [ ${1:-666} -le 256 ] && [ ${2:-666} -le 256 ] \     
 && [ ${3:-666} -le 256 ] && [ ${4:-666} -le 256 ]                                                    
                                                                        }
```

Comment: Is this file the one you're calling `checkip.sh`?  If so, then the `#!/bin/bash` at the top is irrelevant.  When you `source` the file, it ignores the `#!` line and attempts to parse the contents as `zsh` code (or whatever shell you're using).  If the syntax in the function is not valid zsh syntax, then the definition or eventual execution will fail.

Comment: got it. did not know zsh syntax is different from bash.

Comment: Would you also expect your Ada code to function properly in a Fortran compiler? `bash` is not `zsh`, even though there is a lot of common ground between the two...

Comment: @twalberg I have lots of functions that work without any problem in both `bash` and `zsh` but for some of them including `checkip.sh` it does not work, I was looking for a solution to be able to use my functions in both env without modifying the source codes.

Answer (score 2):

We need the `${=specs}` syntax around there in zsh, something like below:

```sh
local IFS=.
if [[ -n ${ZSH_VERSION-} ]]; then
  set -- ${=1}
else
  set -- ${1}
fi
```

It seems that zsh does not expand parameters here as with bash according to the zsh manual:

> ${=spec}
>
> [...snip...]
>   This forces parameter expansions to be split into separate words before substitution, using IFS as a delimiter. This is done by default in most other shells.
>
> -- [`zshexpn(1)` 14.3 Parameter Expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion)